# What's the best way to override a model that is defined inside a plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add validations, methods, etc. to a model that is defined inside a plugin. What's the best way to do this? Would it be safe to copy the model file to the app/models directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin is on [github](http://github.com) you may want to think about forking it and adding the changes.

Comment: Monkeypatching the model is ok, but if you can spend the time to fork the plugin, that's the best way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always go for monkey-patching in that way you don't have to touch the actual plugin. eg.

```
      class YourModel
         validate_uniqueness_of :some_field
      end
```

this patch either you can write as plugin itself or just can be required before use.